# Better performance when generating random array int[]

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am making program to campare sorting algorithms.
I am using big amount of numbers. I have a performance problem in creating array full of random numbers.

Is there any way to make it faster?

Currently I am using:

```
int[] temp = new int[length];      
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
   temp[i] = generator.nextInt(temp.length * 10);
}
```

where

```
generator = new Random();
```

Comment: Can you describe this performance problem that you mention?  What is the value of `length`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want but why don't you use Math.random() to obtain those values?

Comment: The value is from 1 to 100 000 and it takes (for me) 1 min. 36 sec. 644 ms. And I must to use value from 1 to 1 000 000. That's 1000000! generate Random number.

Comment: @Anton Garcia Dosil
Is Math.random faster?

Comment: @AntonGarciaDosil [That method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random\(\)) uses a memoized `java.util.Random` behind the scenes, and it would be clumsier since it returns a `double`.

Comment: Isn't `Math.random()` JavaScript?

Comment: try reading this article, maybe it will help you: [Alternatives to java.util.Random](http://javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/generators_overview.shtml)

Comment: @JimBlackler [`Math.random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

Comment: Ok if you need that number span I guess you should use Random()

Comment: Well I never. I guess that's why they call it "Java"Script.

Comment: Have you thought of multithreading the array creation?

Comment: I think I found the solution: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @Gh61 I copied your codes into a junit test class, replaced the `length` with `1000000`. run the test, it took less than 0.5s. I even put the new Random() in your for loop. it took longer for sure, but <3s. Are you sure the array-creation is the bottleneck ? or are you running it on a machine with a 386cpu? (my laptop is old thinkpad T60 with Archlinux installed)

Comment: @Gh61 oh, sorry, you mean 1000000! .... I didn't think the "!" as a mathematical symbol. :(

Comment: Are you creating an array of length `factorial(1000000)` ?

Comment: @DavidSoroko No, it was multiple arrays with diferent lengths. factorial(1000000) is the count of random numbers I needed to generate.
The question is old and already answered. I only edited the Title, so it can reach more people, that are searching solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it faster, you may write your own random number generator,
which is less random but faster.

Unfortunatley this is c code, but you may translate to java:
Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

For your application this will be sufficient. For crypthography not.

```
m_w = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero */
m_z = <choose-initializer>;    /* must not be zero */

uint get_random()
{
    m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
    m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
    return (m_z << 16) + m_w;  /* 32-bit result */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can try to speed it up a little by calculating the maximum of the for-loop and newtInt argument only once or directly use your `length` variable. And by having only one static Random generator.

```
private static final Random GENERATOR = new Random();   

int[] temp = new int[length];      
int tempLen = length * 10;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   temp[i] = GENERATOR.nextInt(tempLen);
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I suspect any modern JVM will effectively optimize that for you.

Comment: I, too do it that way, on big loops, but the main spot is the random code. not the length getter.

Comment: of course is it the random. but since u use the standard random, u should do it like this ;)

Comment: This should really just be a comment. It's a good point, but doesn't address the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Uncommons Maths](http://maths.uncommons.org/) library. It advertises various random number generators which are implemented for high performance compared to `java.util.Random`, among other things. Have a look at [`XORShiftRNG`](http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/random/XORShiftRNG.html) for example:

> Very fast pseudo random number generator. See [this page](http://school.anhb.uwa.edu.au/personalpages/kwessen/shared/Marsaglia03.html) for a
>   description. This RNG has a period of about 2^160, which is not as
>   long as the [`MersenneTwisterRNG`](http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/random/MersenneTwisterRNG.html) but it is faster.

Disclaimer: I personally have no experience with this library and simply found it searching google.

Answer (score 1):

What I am seeing is that your bottleneck is repetitive random() operations. If you could reduce it to less random() operations you'd eventually have faster performance.

I would generate a very large string, byte array or number to begin with. This would lead to just one large initial random data creation. Consider it a pool of data to subsequently work with.

Subsequent operations would then just iterate through this to extract the random numbers.

This way you generate random data only once thereby eliminating your bottleneck on random data generation.

Make sure you use psudo random and not true random as true random would most definitely hurt your performance.

Comment: That or procedural generation of a random array.